# I want to create a row in bootstrap 3/4 grid system which contain 7 images only inside a row

Tags: design-patterns, bootstrap-4, responsive-design, containers, row

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5vuB.jpg)[Hello hope you are well!
I want to create a row with grid system in bootstrap 3/4 which contain seven images horizontal for desktop and
display  for one column in mobile for all types of devices  to be responsive, but all seven images should placed   inside only a single row like a picture.
If anyone have any answer please reply me.][2]***

Comment: You'd want to use the Bootstrap grid system. Using the grid system will allow you to have responsive layouts like you're looking for. Check out this article to learn more: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: Thanks Andrew but there  are 7 images I want to placed to only in  row, but with 6 images inside a row is easy simple .col-md-2, but with 7 seven images is little difficult.